# Orthogonally diagonalizable matrix and orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

How is an orthogonally diagonalizable matrix related to eigenvectors and an orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 3):

"Orthogonally diagonalizable" means precisely "has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors".

Comment: Is it a definition of orthogonally diagonalizable?

Comment: It usually is. What's your definition?

Comment: A matrix A is orthogonally diagonalizable when there exists an orthogonal matrix P such that P^( −1) AP = D is diagonal.

Comment: You should give it a try and convince yourself that property is exactly the same as having an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. Start with the case where $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: @Walter note that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal if and only if the columns of $P$ are a basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

We say that a matrix $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable if we can write $A=D^{-1}SD$ such that $S$ is a diagonal matrix and its diagonal elements are eigenvalues of $A$ and rows of $D$ are eigenvectors of $A$. Rows of $D$ are a orthonormal basis, it means they or mutually perpendicular and because of this fact $D^T=D^{-1}$.

As an example you can find all symmetric matrices orthogonally diagonalizable.